# can we say that any 2D shapes or plane figures are also a curve in geometry

Tags: geometry, curves

Definition of curve is "A curve is a shape or a line which is smoothly and continuously drawn in a plane having a bent or turns in it". So according to the definition of curve, can we say that any 2D shapes or plane figures are also a curve in geometry?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ... a curve in $\color{red}{\text{some}}$ geometrical system...

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> To answer the question properly, we need working definitions of _curve_ and _plane figure_. These are more subtle concepts than casual intuition and usage suggest, and are not standard across all of mathematics. Anyway, it would help to give more of an idea what's meant here by these terms.

Comment: @Community I have edited the question. See it

Answer (score 0):

A disc, for example the set in an xy-coordinate system defined by $x^2+ y^2\le 1$, is a "plane figure" but is NOT a "curve".

Comment: Sorry but the frontier of a disk for example is a curve...

Comment: ??Yes that is exactly what I said!  But the disk itself is NOT  a curve.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve) defines it:

> A 'topological curve' can be specified by a continuous function  $\gamma \colon I \rightarrow X$ from an interval  $I\subset$  $\mathbb{R}$ into a topological space $X$. Properly speaking, the ''*curve*'' is the *image* of $\gamma$.

We can actually simplify this in our case to just:

> A curve is the image of a continuous function $\gamma \colon [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

If we assume this definition of a curve, then a '2d plane figure' is just a special case, for which $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$. This is called a closed curve. Examples would be circles, triangles, any polygons.

But as @george-ivey pointed out solid 2d shapes are not curves, only the boundary is a curve.

Comment: Can you explain why (using the definition of a curve that you gave) a solid 2d shape is not a curve?