# Parametrized curve in R^2

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

We can define a parametrized curve in ${ℝ}^2$ as a function $r:I→{ℝ}^2$ where $I$ is an interval of $ℝ$ and we can write $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$.
Does a parametric curve whose graph is the same as a closed disk in ${ℝ}^2$ described by the equation : $x^{2}+y^{2}\le r^{2}$ exist?
The question might be stupid but i am trying to find an answer to this question using the formal definition of a parametric curve.
The graph of a parametric curve is defined by the set:
{(x(t),y(t)): $t \in I$}

Comment: Are you asking for the parametrization of a disk or the parametrization of its perimeter?

Comment: Of the disk it self that is why i used the less or equal symbol

Comment: Then if I'm not mistaken you'd need $\mathbf r(u,v): I\times J\to\mathbf R^2$. Namely, two parameters or am I confusing things?

Comment: I thought it'd be $\mathbf r(u,v)=(u\cos v, u\sin v)$, for $u\in(0,r)$ and $v\in(0,2\pi)$...

Comment: For sure you can make a two parameter function that its image is a disk, but the question remains can you also do that with a single parameter function.

Comment: Maybe an infinitely compressed spiral?

Comment: I think this is roughly the concept that @Lee Mosher is describing but applied to a disk instead of a square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (continuous) parametric curve whose image is the disc $\{(x,y) \mid x^2 + y^2 \le r\}$ does indeed exist. *However*, the construction of such an object usually doesn't occur until a higher level course in topology and/or analysis.

The first similar example one usually encounters is the [Peano space filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) which, rather than having image being a disc, instead has image being a square such as $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. You can read about the construction at that link; in very brief outline, one constructs, ***very*** carefully, a sequence of parameterized curves with image contained in square such that the sequence gets denser and denser in the square, and such that the sequence converges, in a ***very*** strong sense, to the desired parameterized curve whose image is the whole square. The necessity for employing high powered topological tools arises from the need to generalize convergence concepts from sequences of points to sequences of functions.

The difference between squares and discs, while important from the standpoint of Euclidean geometry, is not so important from the standpoint of topology: every square and every disc are homeomorphic to each other, in topological language. It follows from this statement that the existence of a parameterized curve with image equal to a square easily implies the existence of a parameterized curve with image equal to a disc.

Comment: I also learned in vector analysis about the differentiation of  parametric curves. Does the same concept of differentiation work in such curves because in a "normal" curve the derivative at a point is a vector tangent to the curve. What does tangent mean in an internal point of a disk for example?

Comment: Also i found an answer in the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4439141/1248634 that claims that a solid 2d shape cannot be considered a curve

Comment: These are interesting issues, although they are beyond the scope of your current question. You could consider asking them in a separate post, but it is usually regarded as an improper use of this site to ask and answer further questions in the comments to an actual answer.

Comment: One thing I'll say, though, is that a space filling curve *cannot* be differentiable. To put it another way, if you had asked a different question with an additional hypothesis, namely that $r$ be differentiable, then the answer would have been "*No such curve exists*".

Comment: Also, in that question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4439141/1248634, unlike your post the concept of "curve" is not precisely defined at all, so it's not surprising that there might be a contradiction with this post.